# Shift box of the checkbox component to the right of label

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, sass

Im new to vue. May I ask about this?
So, I have checkbox component and I want to shift the "box" of this component to the right side of label text in other component (e.g Card, by default the box is on the left). But I want it to be like a slot, conditional, or maybe using props/modifier (so I can choose the requirement, is it left or right checkbox). Is it possible? Here are my code

Checkbox on Card component:

```
<template>
 //component code

    <Checkbox  class="my-checkbox" ref="myCheckbox" v-model="checkedValue" v-if="multiselect"><slot>{{ text }}</slot></Checkbox>
 
 //component code
</template>
```

Checkbox template:

```
<div class="my-cb">
  <input
    :id="cb"
    v-model="computedValue"
    type="checkbox"
    :disabled="disabled"
    :required="required">
    <label :for="cb">
       <slot />
    </label>
</div>
```

Edit: Thanks to Lais Frigerio, solved perfectly

Comment: You could use flexbox to change label position with order property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code example with flexbox:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.left label { order: 2; }
.left input { order: 1; }

.right label { order: 1; }
.right input { order: 2; }
```

```html
<div class="flex left">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <label>Teste 2</label>
</div>

<div class="flex right">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <label>Teste 2</label>
</div>
```

Comment: This one is works perfectly, thank you so much! @Lais Frigerio